# Finding the Extrema Non-differentiable Functions.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-optimization

Are there any examples of solving for the global maximum of a non-differentiable function where you:

1. Construct a series of differentiable functions that approach the non-differentiable function in the limit
2. Show the maximum of each differentiable function converges to some value, which is thus your answer.

For all I know, the procedure above is fatally flawed (or there are trivial examples, I would be most interested in non-trivial examples) in some way, if that is the case let me know.

I am specifically interested in examples involving absolute values.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? Are you looking for examples or counter-examples?

Comment: Examples, let me know what was confusing and I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

Let $F_n(x) = \sqrt{x^2+2^{-n}}$. It is not hard to show that $F_n(x) \to \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.
Every $F_n$ is differentiable and has a local minimum at 0, and indeed so does |x|.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That is not what I wanted because the right and left derivatives are different for $\sqrt{x^2}$ at zero just like $\left | x \right |$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ _is_ $|x|$. Every function in the sequence $F_n$ is differentiable at 0, and the sequence approaches the limit $|x|$.

Comment: That maybe so, but is every $F_n$ a differentiable function, i.e. has a derivative for each point in its domain?

Comment: I honestly don't know that's why I am asking.

Comment: Okay, my bad. I got out the pen and paper, and it looks you won't get a singularity.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you outlined is commonly used in practice.  If your original problem has some nice properties, such as convexity, the approach will work well.  For example, the [soft maximum](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/13/soft-maximum/) is a common way to construct a series of smooth, convex approximations to the maximum function.

Comment: Ha, I actually read part of your blog, but didn't realize the soft maximum approached the function in the limit. Was actually trying to help solve this problem: http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/1715/optimize-an-objective-function-with-absolute-value-function which may or not be a good use of the soft maximum

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab at why the problem is hard for highly non-differentiable but continuous functions. So say $f$ is nowhere differentiable on $[a,b]$. I claim that there are either infinitely or no local extrema of $f$. (By local extrema, I mean extrema that occur in the interior of the interval $[a,b]$.)

Indeed, suppose there were finitely many, say $c_1 < c_2<\dots f(c_2)$. Then we can take the global maximum of $f$ on $[c_1, c_2]$, which occurs at an *interior* point; it is thus a local extremum of $f$.

If $f$ is a monotone function, then it is a theorem of Lebesgue that it is differentiable a.e. In particular, the above reasoning shows that the existence of finitely many local extrema implies that $f$ is differentiable a.e.

Comment: @Jonathan: I was talking about extrema not at the endpoints.

Comment: What if you know it has a global maximum, does that change anything?

Comment: are you assuming that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, I was (edited again for clarity!).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but the second paragraph needs work. You probably did not mean $c_2<\dots f(c_2)$. And the part about maximum on $[c_1,c_2]$ being interior is somewhat unclear. (There was a question about it recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/539563/)